# Krea Content Elements loses content when there's a validation error

Tags: validation, bug, content-elements

We're using Krea Content Elements (http://www.krea.com/content-elements) on a new site and have discovered that if a standard EE validation issue fires, (i.e. a required field missing content) that on the subsequent page load the content you had added to your Content Elements field is lost! Bit of a showstopper... anyone aware of a resolution to this, in fact can anyone reproduce?

Comment: Note, I'm also using BoldMinded Publisher and BW Required Category.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce on CE 1.6.5 at least. Tried saving an entry w/o a Title and then had some content in a Heading and WYSIWIG field in a Content Elements field - hit submit and was redirected back with the content intact.

If you're able to reproduce consistently on a clean install I'd say report a bug.

Comment: Wondering if this might be a Content Elements / Publisher conflict so going to step back, remove add-ons one by one and see where I end up. :) Thanks!

Comment: Well after some further investigation it has to be some conflict between Krea Content Elements and BoldMinded Publisher I think. Logging a bug report... :)

Comment: Yup, makes sense that there is a conflict there. Publisher doesn't save the data as channel entries so there are a lot of ways / places it could err with regards to other third party add ons :-/

Comment: @NathanPitman for clarity could you confirm the fix?